Purcell's Electricity and Magnetism and Special Relativity
I am a student in electrical engineering and currently, I am doing my master's. Recently, I have started reading Purcell's book "Electricity and Magnetism" and words cannot describe how much I loved the first 4 chapters (I tried to solve every problem and exercise). As you might know, this book treats magnetism through special relativity and I do not have any knowledge about special relativity. I've never liked mechanics and from what I know, special relativity is related to mechanics. So, my question is that what is a good and small resource so I can learn enough about special relativity and then jump back to Purcell's book. I really appreciate your help.

This question is similar to: What are good books for special relativity?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

It may not be possible to "finish off" with SR by reading one book and then jumping back to focus on EM. SR is a deep subject so I would advise you to find a resource that can both introduce you to the fundamentals and also serve as a reference for more specific things later on.

I believe that the series “Six ideas that shaped physics” by Thomas Moore   has a unit on relativity (unit R) and one on E&M (unit E) wherein there is a discussion of magnetism in terms of relativity.

Since Purcell's "Electricity and Magnetism" is volume 2 of the Berkeley Physics Course, it might be good to consult volume 1: Kittel's "Mechanics".  Presumably, students following the sequence would have seen the Relativity chapters in Kittel before seeing Relativity used in Purcell.
